# Postgresql: Foreign key violations when importing tables from csv files using copy_expert offered by psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

Here is a recreation of the problem statement.

The database schemas for two tables (say `Tab1` and `Tab2`) have been given in a file called (say) `schemas.ddl`. Multiple integrity constraints (including foreign keys) exist between these two tables. The data of these two tables has been given in `data1.csv` and `data2.csv` respectively. I am required to get the data from these csv files into the tables.

This is how I do it:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=postgres, user=postgres, host=localhost, port=5432)
cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute the schema, this works fine
cur.execute(open(schemas.ddl, "r").read())

files = ["data1.csv", "data2.csv"]

# Iterate through files to add data
for i in range(1,3):
    copy_sql = "copy Tab"+str(i)+" from stdin with csv header delimiter as ',' null as 'null'"
    with open(files[i-1],'r') as f:
        cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=f)
```

That is, I use `copy_expert()` as shown to copy the first file's data and then the second file's data. This however causes foreign key constraints (and other custom constraints) to be violated as the data is entered.

Is there a way to check the integrity of the entered data at commit, and not after every command? I've tried `cur.execute("SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;")` but that doesn't change anything.

---

## Solution

by Anand Sowmithiran

Just make the foreign keys and the constraints as `deferrable`. Example:

```
Foreign Key(A) references B deferrable;
```

Or if you trust the data to be correct, just disable all triggers and re-enable them after copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those FK constraints must be created with DEFERRABLE initially, only then it can be deferred by using the SET command. Alternatively, you can turn off all `triggers` on those 2 tables and then do the bulk copy operation, and then enable the triggers. PG uses triggers to enforce FK constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE tab2 DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
 --run your program---
--and then enable triggers
ALTER TABLE tab2 ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

Comment: Disabling the triggers only cause FK constraint to be not checked, however the SET Constraints ALL Defferred' affects the UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, REFERENCES (foreign key), and EXCLUDE constraints. See documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-set-constraints.html)

Comment: To know how to create FK constraint with `Deferrable` initially, see this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166368)